# Using the library Simple_html_dom, it is necessary to close a "session" of file_get_html?

Tags: php

Developed a method to get a value from a page, however I pass an array of links to this method and it will returning the value of each link. The problem is that it only returns the last value of the given link, ignoring the other links. You must perform some "closure" method to send the links to other processes?
Follows the method of processing and insertion:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($link);$i++){
    $id=explode("/",$link[$i]);
    $id=$id[3];
    $url=(String)$link[$i];

    $data=$ListaDAO->GetDataCur($id);
    // Seta os dados
    //echo "ID>".$id." URL> ".$url." DATE>".$data;
    $DataSetterLista = $ListaDAO->DataSetter($Lista,$id,$url,$data);


    //Insere os dados
   $ListaDAO->InsertData($DataSetterLista);
   $insert = TRUE;`
```

---

```
public function GetDataCur($id){

    $user=$id;
    $url="http://lattes.cnpq.br/".$user; 
    $html= file_get_html($url);
    echo $html;        
    $informacoes= $html->find('ul[class=informacoes-autor]');

    foreach ($informacoes as $inf) {
            $divInf=$inf->find('li');
            $date=  explode(" em ", $divInf[1]);
            $date=$date[1];
            $values=  explode("/",$date);
            $ano=explode("<",$values[2])[0];
            $mes=$values[1];
            $dia=$values[0];
            $date=$ano."-".$mes."-".$dia;
            return $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `return` in the `foreach` loop. So it will return from the function the first time through the loop. Where do you set `$date`?

Comment: Please update the question. There's no formatting in comments, so don't put long code there.

Comment: You're still returning from the loop, so you'll only do the first iteration. How do you expect to return multiple dates? Maybe you should put them into an array and return the array after the loop is done?

Comment: When forwarding a list of links for the method that will get the date and then it returns an error occurs on the links. I took a echo $html variable in the code that receives the page and returns only the last link of the source code, in others this message appears: ". There was a problem displaying the requested page."
Must be some problem in file_get_html method simple_html_dom library.

Comment: `echo $html` won't do anything useful. `$html` is a `Simple HTML DOM` object, not a string that can be printed.

Comment: What I meant is that when I give a variable to echo $html it generates me the source code of the page. So I did a test to create a for according to the quantity of links that I have and try to view the source code of these links, which only returned the last error and appeared in other than the code can be loaded. Even the $html be a Simple HTML DOM object, I give print it can return the source code of the web page.